# How to know Bootstrap button state in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a button like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary timer" id="s-timer">
    Start timer
</button>
```

In jQuery, how can I know whether the button is clicked in or out?

I know I can just have a `.click()` event, but I specifically want to know what sort of click it is? I want to know whether the person has pressed the button in, or whether they are doing the opposite.

Thanks

Comment: .click(event); the event object should have a "type" have you looked at it?

Comment: Or jquery .mousedown() .mouseup() events;

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jabocoriwu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no state associated with the buttons out of the box, this is something you have to implement yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I implemented it by using jQuery to add or remove an "active" class - and then just check for its presence to determine if the button is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually.

**2 jQuery events:**

[Mousedown](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) and 
[Mouseup](https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary timer" id="s-timer">
    Start timer
</button>
```

```js
$('#s-timer')
    .mousedown(function () {
        $(this).addClass('clicked-class');
    })
    .mouseup(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked-class');
    });
```